# Rails fields_for f.select params not submitting on New/Create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, fields-for, nested-form-for

The problem I am having is that my select field options are not passing the attributes params to be saved; however, if the select is changed to a text_field, the field does save. So the issue seems to be in my view. The other parts of the r.fields_for are all also saving.

**View**

```
<%= f.fields_for (:report) do |r| %>
<%= r.select :report_status, ['Ordered', 'Received'], :include_blank => 'Select One' %>
<label for="report_status">Report Status</label>
```

On *edit* action of the nested model, this select works fine, the only difference being form for.

I have also tried to setup it up in a more verbose way:

```
<% report_array = ['Select', 'Ordered', 'Received'] %>
<%= r.select(:report_status, options_for_select(Array[*report_array.collect {|v,i| [v,report_array.index(v)] }])) %>
```

It's not passing them at all, not even blank. Any ideas what could be causing this?

*Updated:*

**HTML Output**

```
<select name="project[report_attributes][report_status]" id="project_report_attributes_report_status" class="initialized"><option value="0">Select</option> <option value="1">Ordered</option> <option value="2">Received</option></select>
```

Comment: Can you post your new and create methods of your controller and the complete log as well?

Comment: I already answered this question with my solution.

Answer (score 1):

This issue had everything to do with MaterializeCSS, a newer front-end framework I've chosen to try out. I should have removed all possible factors. I didn't consider that as playing a role. So I applied browser-default as the { :class => "browser-default" } and voila. It saved.

Which this being a solution still kind of confuses me, because the selections work fine on the edit using the materializecss select. But I guess I have seen stranger things.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the HTML output code o see the final select tag that's generated but I think you may need it like
    [['Ordered','Ordered'],['Received','Received']]

Comment: Yeah, I see what you're saying and I tried that as well. Currently my html output is: <select name="project[report_attributes][report_status]" id="project_report_attributes_report_status" class="initialized"><option value="0">Select</option> <option value="1">Ordered</option> <option value="2">Received</option></select>

Comment: So it seems it would show the same thing as the array you're describing. Which would be the options with values: 0, 1, 2. Is that what you were recommending basically? Or in this case that you're saying, the value Ordered for Ordered.

Comment: I have also updated the post to contain the html output.